# Как узнать IP aдрес клиента в websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

Как я могу узнать адрес подключения в библиотеке websockets ?

```
async def main():
    global server
    server = await websockets.serve(
        on_connect,
        '0.0.0.0',
        9000,
        subprotocols=['ocpp1.6']
    )
    logging.info("Server Started listening to new connections...")
    await server.wait_closed()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/server.html#websockets.server.WebSocketServerProtocol.remote_address

В хандлере on_connect атрибут вэбсокет а remote_address